# Android google map add poly-line method to draw horizontal/vertical line, parallel line

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

Android google map add poly-line :

I have checked google documentation on how to add poly-line on google map. We can add poly-line passing through at least two points.

```
// Add a polyline to the map.
   Polyline polyline1 = googleMap.addPolyline((new PolylineOptions())
               .clickable(true)
               .add(new LatLng(-35.016, 143.321),
                        new LatLng(-34.747, 145.592),
                        new LatLng(-34.364, 147.891),
                        new LatLng(-33.501, 150.217),
                        new LatLng(-32.306, 149.248),
                        new LatLng(-32.491, 147.309)));
```

ref:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/polygon-tutorial

I want to know weather we can able to achieve following things using poly-line,

- Draw a vertical, horizontal line passing through a point given
- Can we draw parallel line to first poly-line given offset distance
- Basically i want to draw a grid of 2x2 km around a specific location point

Any help will be appreciated ..Thanks

Comment: Checkout SphericalUtil.computeOffset to determine the points from a center point.  http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html

Comment: Cool....looks like it covers all information what i am looking for...let me give a try...Once again thanks for valuable help.